# How to update a single field using restful?

Tags: java, mysql, json, rest

How to update a single field using restful?

What I want is to update only data, for update all date use methods post.

My code:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}/{idUsuario}/{usuario}")
@Consumes({"application/json"})
public int edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Activo entity) {
    em.merge(entity);
    return entity.getIdActivo();
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code that you've tried so far...

Comment: My code:   @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    public int edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Activo entity) { em.merge(entity); }

Comment: You can edit your post, and put your code. :)

Comment: If you can form an understandable question I can probably help.